# typedef an sc_fixed but got template error

Tags: systemc

Trying to define a simple sc_fixed type in Visual Studio 2017:

```
#include <systemc.h>
#include <sysc/datatypes/fx/sc_fixed.h>   # just in case
....
typedef sc_fixed<16, 4> fixed_type;
....
```

This typedef line resulted an error:

```
E0864: sc_fixed is not a template
```

Had no idea why this error popped, even included sysc/datatypes/fx/sc_fixed.h. Why does it say "not a template"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From INSTALL file shipped with SystemC

> SystemC 2.3 includes a fixed-point package that is always built.
> When compiling your applications with fixed-point types, you still have
> to use compiler flag -DSC_INCLUDE_FX. Note that compile times increase
> significantly when using this compiler flag.

Using your code as an example

```
#include <systemc.h>
#include <sysc/datatypes/fx/sc_fixed.h>

#include <iostream>

typedef sc_dt::sc_fixed<16, 4> fixed_type;

int sc_main(int, char**){
    fixed_type ft(1.25);
    std::cout << "ft = " << ft << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Gives me the output

```
ft = 1.25
```

As a caveat it is best to check the docs for your particular version of SystemC as I believe this `#define` *may* have been removed in 2.3.3 (I am using 2.3.2) I am not certain.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same type of error message in one of my C++ programs - **E0864 - unique_ptr is not a template**

I managed to get rid of this error in my program by adding this to my header file.

`#include <memory>`

My program managed to compile okay using this.  I am using Visual Studio 2019 if that helps.